# Drag and drop reset button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery I would like to have a reset button that can reset my droppable back to it's original position.. but I don't know how to start with that.. Whenever the reset button pressed the icons all will revert back to it's original location.

**jsFiddle**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/xInfinityMing/tsc0no9g/
```

**Java:**

```
$(function() {
$("#dragIcons img").draggable({
revert: "invalid",
refreshPositions: true,
drag: function(event, ui) {
 ui.helper.removeClass("end-draggable");
 ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
 ui.helper.addClass("end-draggable");
 ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
}
});
$("#briefcase-full").droppable({
over: function(event, ui) {
$(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/yosemite-flat/512/Folder-icon.png")');
  },
out: function(event, ui) {
  $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snow_sabre_silver/512/folder_web_upload.png")');
  },
drop: function(event, ui) {
  $(this).parent().css('background-image','url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/yosemite-flat/512/Folder-icon.png")');
  if ($("#briefcase").length == 0) {
    $("#briefcase-droppable").html("");
  }
    ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
    $("#briefcase-droppable").append(ui.draggable);
  }
  });
});
```